# Can .each have different GC impacts compared to .map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, garbage-collection, iterator

Does one of these two garbage collect differently, or at they the same?

```
array_of_strings.each do |str|
  MailerClass.some_template(str).deliver_later
end
```

vs.

```
array_of_strings.map do |str|
  MailerClass.some_template(str).deliver_later
end
```

I've formatted the question for mailer objects and task-queue stuff because it's what I have been working on recently, but if this will unduly complicate answers then I can reword that to be more generic.

---

context, as relevant:

> I considered that `.map` would return an object with a pointed to each
>   Object that was created, and that `.each` would not. *[this seems to
>   not be the case]*
>
> I have a worker machine that leaks memory until crashing — all
>   happening in one event in which this pseudo-code example is the
>   central action. When I changed it from `.each` to `.map` then the
>   memory leak stopped, but I don't know how that GC is happening in
>   regards to these methods.

Comment: Why would you use `map` in this instance?

Comment: I considered that `.map` would return an object with a pointed to each Object that was created.  `.each` would not.  I have an worker machine that leaks memory until crashing — all happening in one event in which this pseudo-code example is the central action.  When I changed it from `.each` to `.map` then the memory leak stopped, but I don't know that GC is happening because of these methods, per-se.

Comment: you can count the objects yourself before you run that loop and after you run it with http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/ObjectSpace.html#count_objects-method and see if there are more objects allocated, I doubt there will be any difference

Answer (score 1):

Since map returns an Array of the results of evaluating the block with each member of array_of_strings, there is going to be at least one extra object to be collected.

Comment: How does ruby keep track of the objects created within each of `.each` blocks that is executed?

Comment: Any objects created within the each block are marked for GC when they go out of scope (end of that iteration of each) unless a reference is kept elsewhere, same with map except it adds the return value from each iteration to an array to return at the end.  In this case there are also mailer jobs created which are added to a queue so a reference to them is held in the queue so they wouldn't be marked for GC yet.

Comment: Thanks, I clearly need to think more on why `.map` solve the memory leak, despite that similar numbers of emails were being sent.  I was hoping to 'force' this question toward the reality of `.map` creating an improvement, and then get an answer to why.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which exact Ruby implementation you use, the implementation of `Enumerable#map` may be written in Ruby, Smalltalk, RPython, ECMAScript, C#, Java, Go, Objective-C, C++, C, or any number of other languages, but its workings are always going to look like this:

```
module Enumerable
  def map
    return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?
    [].tap {|result| each {|el| result << yield el }}
  end
end
```

`map` *must* call `each`, there's simply no other way for it to iterate. So, it will allocate the exact same objects that `each` would allocate *plus* the additional result `Array`, i.e. exactly one more object than `each` would.

Actually, many Ruby implementations override `Enumerable#map` with `Array#map` which is more efficient than the generic `Enumerable` version. They usually iterate over the `Array` elements directly, without calling `each`, kind of like this:

```
class Array
  def map
    return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?

    result = []

    i = -1
    while i += 1 <= size
      result << yield @__entries__[i]
    end
  end
end
```

This is more efficient than the generic `Enumerable#map`, since it uses special knowledge about how to iterate the `Array` in order to avoid the method call overhead to `each`. Note, however, that `each` would be implemented in the exact same way, unless the implementors are incredibly stupid, so the end result is the same: `map` will still allocate exactly one object more than `each`, it's just saving one method call.

Note that, since you ignore the return value of `map`, the extra object becomes eligible for garbage collection immediately. However, until then, it holds references to all the objects returned by the `deliver_later` method, whatever they are.

So, the differences between the two pieces of code are:

- with `each`, the return value of `deliver_later` is ignored and becomes eligible for garbage collection immediately
- with `map`, there is an additional `Array` allocated which keeps references to the return values of all the `deliver_later` calls inside the block, and thus keeps those objects alive until *after* the call to `map` returns, then, the `Array` and thus all the objects it references will become eligible for garbage collection at the same time

Comment: This is an extremely thorough and worthwhile answer.

Comment: BTW: I tried to figure out what exactly the return value of `deliver_later` is, by tracing it through the ActionMailer and ActiveJob source code, but doing that statically just with GitHub, GitHub Search and Find-on-Page in my browser proved to be too twisted, and I didn't feel like installing Rails and loading it up into an IDE.